# Setup Htaccess to use HTTP or HTTPS

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, ssl

currently, the SSL is not working on my site so those people who try to see the website using the HTTPS url will not be able to see it.

So I've tried to setup the htaccess to allow using both URLS HTTP or HTTPS

I used the following rules

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^[^.]+\.[^.]+$
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s on(s)|
RewriteRule ^ http%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]
```

when I go to check on browser it still gives me an error saying that site is not secure.

I also tried using these two rules in the same htaccess but it seems it's not working tho.

So instead I tried to redirect https to http while I fix the SSL, but not it seems it's not working either.

https://help.crucial.com.au/hc/en-gb/articles/115004449827-How-to-Force-SSL-or-Non-SSL-on-your-Website-With-HTACCESS

Does anyone have an idea how to implement this either by adding rules to htaccess or by any other option?

Comment: SSL cert exchange happens before any URL redirect can happen. You have to get right cert installed

Answer (score 0):

1) make sure that SSL certificate  is installed 
2) use "Simple SSL" plugin for WordPress . It will allow to access the site via https and also will fix mixed content issues

Comment: it's not installing. Because it's on the old hosting from where i moved the website from. I don't access to it. This is why im searching im alternative to fix this.
I've had installed that plugin. Did not work. Or does it take time to see any results?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a cpanel certificate for free, go to your cpanel and look for SSL/TLS, then manage ssl, select you domain and auto-refill domain then install.

Adding this code on .htaccess will do a redirect, when someone access your site with http will automatically force to go to your site with https

But first make sure you have installed a valid certificate

```
RedirectMatch 403 \[

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,QSA,L]
```